# Excel Automatic row insertion between two arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, row

In an Excel sheet I'm working on at the moment, I have two arrays that are dynamically linked to a website through a web query. Because of this, the two arrays have rows added or removed quite often.

I would like to have these two dynamic and evolving arrays one on top of the other with a constant offset of two rows separating them.

Example :

> **ARRAY 1**
>
> -Row1
>
> -Row2
>
> -Row3
>
> *-Blank*
>
> *-Blank*
>
> **ARRAY 2**

Would become (if a row is added to the first array)

> **ARRAY 1**
>
> -Row1
>
> -Row2
>
> -Row3
>
> -Row4
>
> *-Blank*
>
> *-Blank*
>
> **ARRAY 2**

Any idea on how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: is it not easyier to have a array per column?

Comment: It would be, but for readability, on top of each other is better :/

Comment: and what exactly do you want? i am not sure what you do have now and what you want?

Comment: Two arrays, one above the other. When a row is added to the top one I'd like to keep the 2 row separation constant between the top and bottom array

Comment: so what have you done so far with integration with the excel

Comment: For the moment I have the two arrays that are created and updated from web queries to the website from which they are from. I have some conditional formatting to change a few colours here and there but haven't managed to get the constant two row offset between them.

Comment: i suggest you sue NPOI for api with excel.. here is also a example for inserting rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673623/npoi-insert-row-like-excel